# Why alarmmanager not exactly repeats an event android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Please help me. Why does AlarmManager  not exactly repeats an event when the repetition period of more than one day?

Here is my code to run AlarmManager. The variable time_period contains the following value 60*1000*60*24*7 which is equal to 7 days. In the end, if I change the date on your phone, the event is triggered by 6-4-7-7-7-7 days.

This can be seen in the logs of the application (See link http://prntscr.com/7kdqbw ) Thanks in advance for your reply.

```
Intent notification = new Intent(this , ServiceReminders.class);     
notification.putExtra("backup", "backup");
AlarmManager alarmManagerBackup = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pibackup = PendingIntent.getService(this, 3, notification, 10);

if (sdkVersion < 19) {
    alarmManagerBackup.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, time_period, pibackup);
}
else if (sdkVersion >= 19) {
    alarmManagerBackup.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, time_period, pibackup);
}

Log.d("ServiceManagerNotification", "AlarmBackup sdkVersion = "+sdkVersion);
```

Comment: you need to receive TimeSet action in your reciever

Comment: I do not understand. You can explain the details? 
alarmManagerBackup.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, time_period, pibackup);
You mean that that it is impossible  transfer a value triggerAtMillistransfer  0? I just need to work out the event directly and  repeated through the period.

Comment: WILD GUESS: You are using API Level 19+. Since API Level 19, Android delivers the alarms **when it wants to**. And, possibly, **if** it wants to.

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly leveraging the inexact alarms by calling [`setInexactRepeating()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)). Unsurprisingly, this results in your alarms being set at inexact intervals.

The problem is further compounded by the fact that you are supplying a custom period. If you do not use one of the pre-defined intervals, then the framework will simply call `setRepeating()` using your interval instead of using `setInexactRepeating()`.

From the documentation for the `intervalMillis` parameter:

> interval in milliseconds between subsequent repeats of the alarm. Prior to API 19, if this is one of `INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES`, `INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR`, `INTERVAL_HOUR`, `INTERVAL_HALF_DAY`, or `INTERVAL_DAY` then the alarm will be phase-aligned with other alarms to reduce the number of wakeups. Otherwise, the alarm will be set as though the application had called `setRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent)`. As of API 19, all repeating alarms will be inexact and subject to batching with other alarms regardless of their stated repeat interval.

In the end, regardless of how you set this alarm, it will be inexact if you set it as a repeating alarm and there isn't a whole lot you can do about it.

If you need more precision, you should use either [`setWindow()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setWindow(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) or [`setExact()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and set the next alarm every time your alarm triggers. Although if you are only performing an action once a week, it is likely that in the end you don't need that precision.

Comment: so I do not need very accuracy. The problem is that the alarm is triggered earlier than is necessary. My period is 7 days, eventually works through  6-4-7-7-7-7 days. I have tried to use a separate these two methods setInexactRepeating ()  and setRepeating (). The result is the same.

Comment: If you want *any* sort of guarantee on when your alarms will be delivered, you cannot use `setInexactRepeating()` or `setRepeating()`. Neither carry guarantees other than that alarms will be delivered in the general vicinity of the interval you request. The bigger the interval, the bigger the "wiggle room" the alarm manager has on when to trigger the alarm.